# Ошибка в параметре для функции из библиотеки

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение

```
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection, linear_model, metrics
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap as ls
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ds, c_v, l_m, ms = datasets, model_selection, linear_model, metrics

blobs = ds.make_blobs(centers=2, cluster_std=5.5, random_state=1)

scorer = ms.make_scorer(ms.accuracy_score)

cv_strat = c_v.StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=20, test_size=0.3, random_state=2).split(blobs[0], blobs[1])
lr_scorin = c_v.cross_val_score(log_reg, blobs[0], blobs[1], scoring=scorer, cv=cv_strat)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, код выдает ошибку index out of range из функций библиотеки sklearn. Что можно сделать и как исправить? Ошибка в последней строчке для оценки работы алгоритма линейной регрессии:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\к3.py", line 47, in <module>
    lr_scorin = c_v.cross_val_score(log_reg, blobs[0], blobs[1], scoring=scorer, cv=cv_strat)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 445, in cross_val_score
    cv_results = cross_validate(estimator=estimator, X=X, y=y, groups=groups,
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 264, in cross_validate
    results = _aggregate_score_dicts(results)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 1692, in _aggregate_score_dicts
    for key in scores[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Добавьте стектрейс с ошибкой.

Comment: спасибо за поправку